# Disable iPhone notification when message displayed on Mac

Tags: iphone, mac, messages, notifications

I have Messages on my MacBook connected to my iPhone, so when my phone gets an SMS message it's displayed on the Mac. But the iPhone also dings and displays a notification of the message.

What I'd like is that the iPhone doesn't do a notification if I'm using the Mac. The best criteria would be that the phone should do a notification if I'm away from the Mac or the Mac is sleeping or in the screensaver, but if I'm near the Mac and it's active, the notifications should just go to the Mac.

Is there a way to set this up?

Comment: The phone won't notify at all if you switch to the Messages app within the first minute of receipt.  I'm not sure there can be a bypass for this, because if you don't acknowledge it on the Mac, the phone will assume you didn't see it & will alert you next.

Comment: That's not what I experienced tonight. I was sitting at the computer and the phone dinged at about the same time that the message notification appeared on my screen.

Comment: On mine, the 'ding' happens on whichever I was last using; the other only notifies if I don't acknowledge I've seen the first. If I'm on the Mac but watching the phone, I will see the notification come at the same time, but it won't ding [unless I ignore it]. As soon as I switch to the message on the Mac, the notification on the phone vanishes.

Comment: The way I get my computer to get notifications is send a random message to myself/some friend on my macbook. That way my macbook will receive all messages first and the phone will only 'ding' if the message on the mac is not read.

Comment: I get the notification on the computer. But I *also* get the ding on the phone.

Comment: Really not sure then, sorry. I only get the initial ding on whichever device I last used. The others stay silent for about a minute & only then ding if I've ignored the initial notification.

Comment: "Last used" may be the problem. When a new text comes in, it could have been hours since the last time I used Messages on either device. There's no reason I would have used it on the Mac last. But I'm working on my Mac now (doing other things, not Messages), I want a new message to come there.

Comment: It's hard to arrange that the last device I used Messages on will be the one I'm using the next time a text comes in.